# Pandas DataFrames KeyError:0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, keyerror

I'm just trying to pull the first column of urls from the table off this site.  And i keep running into KeyError: 0.  I'm just starting to learn python.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "riscribble.py", line 13, in <module>
    lic_link = soup_data[0].find('a').text
  File "C:\Users\rkrouse\Desktop\Python\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1071, in __getitem__
    return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 0
```

Any ideas on why i'm getting this error and/or how to correct would be appreciated.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests as r
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://www.crb.state.ri.us/verify_CRB.php?page=0&letter='

data = r.get(url)

page_data = soup(data.text, 'html.parser')

soup_data = page_data.find('table')

lic_link = soup_data[0].find('a').text

df = pd.DataFrame()

for each in soup_data:
    lic_link = each.find('a').text

    df=df.append(pd.DataFrame({'LicenseURL': lic_link}, index=[0]))

df.to_csv('RI_License_urls.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Imports:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests as r
import pandas as pd
import re
```

**Get your page:**

```
url = 'http://www.crb.state.ri.us/verify_CRB.php?page=0&letter='

data = r.get(url)

page_data = soup(data.text, 'html.parser')
```

**Choose your link:**

```
links = [link.text for link in page_data.table.tr.find_all('a') if re.search('licensedetail.php', str(link))]

links -> 32922

# or

links = [link for link in page_data.table.tr.find_all('a') if re.search('licensedetail.php', str(link))]

links -> <a href="licensedetail.php?link=32922&amp;type=Resid">32922</a>

# or

links = [link['href'] for link in page_data.table.tr.find_all('a') if re.search('licensedetail.php', str(link))]

links -> licensedetail.php?link=32922&type=Resid

# or

links = [r'www.crb.state.ri.us/' + link['href'] for link in page_data.table.tr.find_all('a') if re.search('licensedetail.php', str(link))]

links -> www.crb.state.ri.us/licensedetail.php?link=32922&type=Resid
```

**Finish:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(links, columns=['LicenseURL'])

df.to_csv('RI_License_urls.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `soup_data = page_data.find('table')` to `soup_data = page_data.find_all('table')`. `find` only finds the first matching object, whereas `find_all` finds all the matching objects. See [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#find(name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20**kwargs)) for more information.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests as r
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://www.crb.state.ri.us/verify_CRB.php?page=0&letter='

data = r.get(url)

page_data = soup(data.text, 'html.parser')

soup_data = page_data.find_all('table')

df = pd.DataFrame()

for each in soup_data:
    lic_link = each.find('a').text

    df=df.append(pd.DataFrame({'LicenseURL': lic_link}, index=[0]))

df.to_csv('RI_License_urls.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Also, you could use either `findAll` or `find_all`, they are the same method. It used to be just `findAll`, but I believe they added `find_all` due to PEP8.

Comment: thanks for that.  error's gone, , but it's just printing              LicenseURL
Return to Search Page
Return to Search Page
32922